# Split pandas dataframe string by multiple whitespaces

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

I've searched around and found re.split for a normal string but I can't get it to work in my df

*This is how it differs from similar questions - I need syntax to apply my solution to an entire column at once, not just a single string*

I was previously using

```
 keeptemp  =  myalerts['Temp'].str.split('    ', expand = True)
```

However sometimes I have 4 or 5 spaces which is fine, other times I have 10 so I get empty columns

I need something which defines split by 4 OR MORE white spaces and works within pandas

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you give a sample of your input data with the expected result ?

Comment: I think my question is different, or at least I couldn't answetr my question by looking at that previous one. Maybe I just needed a tiny bit more spoonfeeding, and I got that below, so I hope this is useful for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this regex

```
(\s{4,})
```

\s whitespace 
{4,} at least 4 times

Comment: by this, nissim abehcera meant: `keeptemp  =  myalerts['Temp'].str.split('\s{4,}', expand = True)` or `[ ]{4,}` if you only want to catch whitespaces, because `\s` extends to tabs and eventually newlines

Comment: Works - your comment tells me exactly what to include. Huge thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can try this :

```
keeptemp = myalerts['Temp'].str.split(" +",expand = True)
```

the '+' to say one whitespace or more

Comment: Works - perfect, thanks

Comment: @KieranIngram you're welcome!